# how to break a python list into sublist by separator

Tags: python, list

i have a list like this `[[],[],['a'],['b'],[],[],['c'],['d'],['m']]` and I need to keep the empty list intact, and group the remaining in place, resulting in `[[],[],['a','b'],[],[],['c','d','m']]` 
I tried something like this based on another question but it tends to group the empty array as well. Thanks for any advice

```
my_temp = []
my_final = []
for item in my_array:
  if item != []:
    my_temp.append(item)
  else:
    my_final.append(my_temp);
    my_temp = []
print(my_final);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.  First off, you're adding a list the temp list you're building up, instead of extending it.  Also, there's also an edge cases if your source list doesn't end with an empty list.

One possible way to solve this is to add each item to the last list on the array if that last item has items in it and the target item isn't empty:

```python
my_final = []
for item in my_array:
    if len(my_final) > 0 and len(my_final[-1]) > 0 and len(item) > 0:
        my_final[-1].extend(item)
    else:
        my_final.append(item)
print(my_final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not optimised, but works:

```
my_array = [[],[],['a'],['b'],[],[],['c'],['d'],['m']]

my_temp = []
my_final = []
for item in my_array:
    if not item: # item is an empty list 
        if my_temp: # if we previously have collected items, we add them now to the final list and clear the temp list
            my_final.append(my_temp)
            my_temp = []
        my_final.append(item) # add empty list
    else:
        my_temp += item # keep collecting non-empty items

if my_temp: # same logic as within the loop, add any remaining items to the final list
    my_final.append(my_temp)
    
print(my_final)
```

Output:

```
[[], [], ['a', 'b'], [], [], ['c', 'd', 'm']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problems include:

- You confused `append` and `extend` when adding `my_temp`
- You neglect to append the final accumulated list
- When you hit an empty list, you forget to add it at all: you weren't grouping them, you were *ignoring* them.

Amended code:

```
my_array = [[],[],['a'],['b'],[],[],['c'],['d'],['m']]

my_temp = []
my_final = []
for item in my_array:
  if item != []:
    my_temp.extend(item)
  else:
    my_final.append(my_temp);
    if my_temp:    # Also append item
        my_final.append(item)    
    my_temp = []

if my_temp:
    my_final.append(my_temp)
    
print(my_final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with simple generator:

```
def groups(values):
    group = []
    for value in values:
        if value == []:
            if group != []:
                yield group
                group = []
            yield value
        else:
            group.append(value[0])
    if group != []:
        yield group

l = [[],[],['a'],['b'],[],[],['c'],['d'],['m']]

print(list(groups(l)))
# [[], [], ['a', 'b'], [], [], ['c', 'd', 'm']]
```